# php server https (Request req_FafwbsfPd38bhj) Not a valid URL

Tags: php

I am getting following error when trying to get page url

```
   $YOUR_DOMAIN = $_SERVER['HTTPS'];
$v=$_POST['price'];
$p=$_POST['product'];
$d=$_POST['domain'];

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'usd',
      'unit_amount' => $v,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => $p,
        'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
      ],
    ],    
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  "metadata[domain]"=>$d,
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.php?domain='.$d,
  'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
]);
```

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught (Status 400) (Request
> req_FafwbsfPd38bhj) Not a valid URL

Comment: I don't think `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` returns what I think you think it returns. Try perhaps `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: 'HTTPS'
Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`

Comment: Maybe something like:
`(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to catch both the scheme and the server name.

Comment: @msbit yes that the ultimate way